# Long running Apache processes after Php execution completed

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos5

- Apache/2.2.3
- PHP 5.2.5
- CentOS 5

## Trace

**[Trace details image](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/177258935306837010/)**

- start php
- run script
- run kill (registered Php shutdown function)
- apache still runs for long time, unknown why

This does NOT happen every page load.

**How do I track down what Apache is doing?**